# Should I track who to send notifications to when using websockets or send to all users?

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

I am working on a web application where users have to log in (which gives me a handle that I can track them by in the websocket server) and am wondering whether it is worth it to track them or not. I need to send out a notification to make changes to the home page only if they are on that page. Would it be better to maintain a map of everyone who is on the home page and only send the notification to them, or send the notification to everyone and then have the javascript see if they are on the home page?
Thanks for any input!

Comment: Another option is to have a dedicated websocket path to the homepage (additional connection), so that only users that are currently viewing the homepage will connect to it... If you're not using websockets for anything else, it's an easy and effective solution.

Comment: P.S. using websockets to track users is resource intensive - far better to use the authentication process which is already integrated into each of the request's workflow or use session data.

Comment: On this same train of thought, if I want to send notifications only to specific users would it be better to maintain a map of all the users and their roles (how I decide who gets notifications) or just send to everyone and deal with updating in the javascript only if necessary? Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Websocket (and TCP/IP) Unicasting is less resource intensive than broadcasting.

TCP/IP doesn't really allow broadcasting, so broadcasting is implemented by iterating over the connections and sending each one a message (unicasting).

Having said that, the server's code might be better optimized than your own, so you might get better performance while broadcasting under some circumstances than if you iterated over the connections yourself to run some code on each one. This would be the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Some websocket libraries in the wild have a **PUB/SUB** feature, which let you subscribe connections to a channel that you can publish specific content to.

Knowing whether or not such a feature runs well with respect to performance (etc.), would requires some research into the specific library.